# Coroutines in nested scopes

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I'm writing an Android library and I have a situation (VERY simplified here for example's sake) with an interface where I need to make a function `suspended` to be able to call `Flow.collect` into it.

```kotlin
interface Executor {
   suspend fun <T> execute(flow: Flow<T>)
}

class MyExecutor(): Executor {
   override suspend fun <T> execute(flow: Flow<T>) {
      flow.collect {
         println("execution obtained $it")
      }
   }
}

class A(val scope: CoroutineScope, val classB: B, val executor: Executor) {
   fun executeCommand() {
      scope.launch {
         val command = classB.getCommand()
         executor.execute(command)
      }
   }
}

class B() {
   fun getCommand(): Flow<Int> = flowOf(1)
}
```

The problem I have is that, when I try to use this library from a test app written in Java I'm not able to properly implement the `Executor` interface given its suspended fucntion.

Do you have any suggestion on how to do it?

p.s. A solution would be to make `execute` a normal function and provide `MyExecutor` with a `CoroutineScope` in the constructor, but even if I manage to have a singleton of it for the whole app, it would still be a "nested" scoping, resulting into different workers handling the process.
Although I'm not sure how wrong this is, it sure doesn't sound right

```kotlin
class MyExecutor(val scope: CoroutineScope): Executor {
   override fun <T> execute(flow: Flow<T>) {
      scope.launch {
         flow.collect {
            println("execution obtained $it")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: If this library has to be used in Java, I would provide a "standard" non-coroutine API, with coroutine features provided via extension functions. No one wants to have to work with coroutine contexts and Flows in Java code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Tenfounr04, could you perhaps elaborate on how to achieve that via extension functions (taking into account that internally I would still neet ot use it "as if" it was suspended)?

Comment: I think typical asynchronous APIs in Java use a callback system and ExecutorService to handle the asynchronous work and running the callback on the calling thread.